# How to select a host to serve an application based on the third-level domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, redirect

The question may be pretty simple, and the obvious answer is even more straightforward (it's impossible), but perhaps I am missing something.

I have several physical servers that host custom applications. Every application should have a third-level domain name. For example: `atest.site.com`, `bfive.site.com`, `bmovie.site.com` and so on. I do not know what exactly names could be, but there is a rule telling that server A should serve all applications whose name starts with 'A' (e.g. atest). Server B should serve applications with names starting with 'B' (e.g. bfive and bmovie) and so on. At the same time, I must preserve the application name in the address bar, so a simple redirect like `atest.A.test.com` won't work for me.

It there a way to implement this? What is the best way to do this using DNS/balancer/URL_rewrite/reverse_proxy/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can set up a wild card DNS name for `*.example.com`, which directs all requests to those domains to a particular IP address.

On that host, one can set up a web server with wildcard virtual hosts. For example, in nginx one can define them like this:

```
server {
    server_name ~ ^(.)([^.]+)\.example.com$;

    proxy_pass https://$1.example.com;
}
```

Here we use a regular expression to capture the first letter of the third level domain name and rest of the third level name to a variable. Then we use the first letter in `proxy_pass` to pass the request to desired target.